# AdMob in-game ads

Tags: android, sdk, admob, target

I got the latest AdMob SDK. After i added the activity like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

i got the following error: "Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|
 smallestScreenSize')."

After some diggings here on this support forum i understood that i need to take the Android 3.2 SDK for the AdMob to work.

HOWEVER! My application is targeted for Android 2.1 (and on). 
So if i target the app for the Android 3.2 (only because of AdMob), will it block the phones running Eclair/Froyo/Gingerbread from installing/running my application?

Comment: Need Android 3.2 for Admob!? I don't think this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the Android 3.2 SDK and "compile" against it by setting your project.properties file to `target=android-13`.  You can still have your apps run on Android 2.1 and above by setting `android:minSdkVersion="7"`.

Comment: I understand that, but what guarantee do i have that the AdMob SDK uses components supported by the Android 2.1  SDK and the user will not get some compatibility error?

Comment: The AdMob SDK has a minSdkVersion of 3, which means it has been tested all the way down to Android 1.5. So AdMob guarantees that the user will not get a compatibility error because of the SDK.  AdMob is only forcing you to "compile" against 3.2 or above so that it can optimize for serving ads on tablets.  The only thing that this means for you is that you have to be careful to not use any Android classes or methods that are not supported by 2.1 (there is potential for this pitfall now that you are writing code against the 3.2 SDK).

Comment: Guess it costs alot confusion to developers. And, it doesn't work on 2.1 emulator

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing that this means for you is that you have to be careful to not use any
>   Android classes or methods that are not supported by 2.1

And since you'll never know it... your app will crashes on thousands of devices and know one will know the reason why.

AdMob makes it nearly impossible to do something as simple as:

> I want to support OS 2.2 and newer.

You can do it with nearly everything ELSE... but not AdMob.